# The entity type cannot be configured as complex type because the derivd typ is alredy configred as entity typ. ODataConventionModelBuilder GetEdmModel

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, odata

Background : We were using this code with previous version of OData v4.0.30319 with .net 4.8 it was working fine recently we started to migrate the project to .NET Core 6 and using Microsoft.AspNetCore.OData 8.2.3 and Microsoft.Data.OData 5.8.5

I am facing error while trying to call GetEdmModel in the following code

```
        private static ODataQueryOptions CreateDynamicQueryOptions(ODataQueryOptions<DynamicPoco> originalQuery, Type entityType)
        {
            var entityClrType = entityType;
            var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
            var entityTypeConfiguration = builder.AddEntityType(entityClrType);

            var entitySetConfiguration = builder.AddEntitySet(entityClrType.Name, entityTypeConfiguration);
            
            var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
            var queryContext = new ODataQueryContext(edmModel, entityClrType, originalQuery.Context.Path);

            return new ODataQueryOptions(queryContext, originalQuery.Request);
        }
```

**Got this error**

> System.InvalidOperationException: The entity type 'System.Attribute' cannot be configured as a complex type because the derived type 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonContainerAttribute' is already configured as an entity type.
> at Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.ReconfigureEntityTypesAsComplexType(EntityTypeConfiguration[] misconfiguredEntityTypes)
> at Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.RediscoverComplexTypes()
> at Microsoft.OData.ModelBuilder.ODataConventionModelBuilder.GetEdmModel()
> at ProjectRelated Calls
> at lambda_method5(Closure , Object , Object[] )
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Logged|12_1(ControllerActionInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.g__Awaited|10_0(ControllerActionInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> --- End of stack trace from previous location ---
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)

while executing this line

```
var edmModel = builder.GetEdmModel();
```

it would be of great assistance if someone let me know what I am doing wrong over here or how it can be rectified

this is the type that I am passing

```
public class ErpLicenseViewModel : IErpLicenseModel
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public Guid LicenseGuid { get; set; }
    public DateTime ExpiryDate { get; set; }
    public int Count { get; set; }
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: The error complains that the application itself tried to register *attribute types* like `JsonContainerAttribute` as if they were entities. Are you using reflection to find and register types?

Comment: What is this code trying to do anyway? `ODataQueryOptions` represents a request's operations. A request has no business modifying the application's entire model. There's no reason to create a temporary mini-model either, that's just wasteful. Are you trying to apply the options to an EF or other LINQ query? That's already supported through the various `ApplyTo` overloads

Comment: I have removed all the registration to json but still facing the same error, will try the next and let you know.

Comment: For Second comment I am not using EF at the moment

Comment: What *is* the application doing? What calls `CreateDynamicQueryOptions` ? That probably passed the wrong type. Entity registration doesn't use `ODataQueryOptions` and request processing doesn't register entities. It looks like an arbitrary DTO (with serialization attributes) is forced into an OData model for processing. Which is *very* expensive and completely unexpected. The whole point of OData is the standardized schema and operations, not the naming conventions of some query parameters.

Comment: I have updated the question for Type that I am passing `CreateDynamicQueryOptions ` is called to translate the filters and sort, to use as parameter while calling an Stored procedure

Comment: Is the usage of the default constructor for ODataConventionModelBuilder causing the issue? As per documentation, this constructor uses System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.DefaultAssembliesResolver to get a list of assemblies to build the model).

Shouldn't the code be using ODataConventionModelBuilder(IServiceProvider provider, bool isQueryCompositionMode) constructor?

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved that issue, silly of me should see it in the previous code file first.

in previous code file it was use with some of the constructor parameters.

```
var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration, true);
```

and during migration I have updated it due to a compilation error, call it without any parameters. It was shown to me by one of my seniors, so here is how I resolved it.

Use constructor with parameters:

```
var builder = new 
    ODataConventionModelBuilder(DefaultAssemblyResolver.Default, true);
```

DefaultAssemblyResolver:

```
public class DefaultAssemblyResolver : IAssemblyResolver
{
    private Assembly[] _assemblies = GetAssembliesInteral();

    /// <summary>
    /// This static instance is used in the shared code in places where the request container context
    /// is not known or does not contain an instance of IWebApiAssembliesResolver.
    /// </summary>
    internal static IAssemblyResolver Default = new DefaultAssemblyResolver();

    /// <summary>
    /// Gets the assemblies.
    /// </summary>
    public IEnumerable<Assembly> Assemblies => _assemblies;

    private static Assembly[] GetAssembliesInteral()
    {
        return AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies();
    }
}
```

Thanks to everyone for assitance.